# Getting Authentication failed ERROR when posting data to python eve app

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have created a python eve app and trying to post some data using POST method. but getting the below error:

```
"_status": "ERROR",
"data": [
    {
        "_status": "ERROR",
        "issues": {
            "exception": "Authentication failed."
        }
    }
```

Can any one why this error is coming?

Regards,
Narendra

Comment: please, show how do you send the data and the auth info.

Comment: Please provide more details w.r.t the data being posted and auth info.